# jQuery template rendered output

Tags: jquery, string, templates, dom, jquery-templates

When I pass HTML elementals as strings in my object then they are not converted to elements upon rendering, so my template gets filled like this

```
<tr><td>"<img src="path/pic.png" />"</td></tr>
```

If I pass DOM elementals then I get

```
<tr><td>[Object HTMLImageElement]</td></tr>
```

How can I get the actual image rendered as a DOM element ?

Using jQuery Template plugin should help to greatly reduce the HTML string building usage.

**Edit**:
Simple example below that grabs the DOM elements and then gives it to jquery template, which renders it.

source HTML

```
<div id="source-id"><a href="http://link/to/this.file" title="foo">bar</a> <img src="path/pic1.png" />pic1_text <img src="path/pic2.png" title="picture 2" />pic2_text</div>
<div id="target-id"><div>
```

jquery template

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="linkTemplate"><table><tr><td>${link}</td><td>${img}</td></tr></table></script>
```

jquery

```
var data = {
 'link': '',
 'img': ''
};
var source_data = $('#source-id');
data.link = $(source_data).find('a').eq(0).clone()[0];
data.img = $(source_data).find('img').eq(1).clone()[0];
$('#target-id').html($('#linkTemplate').tmpl(data));
```

Output

```
<table><td>http://link/to/this.file</td><td>[object HTMLImageElement]</td></table>
```

As you can see is the AnchorElement () broken and image is not displayed.
[JS fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/TaSaM/)

Comment: ..and what are we fixing? Provide an example of what you've tried.

Comment: Could you post your jquery code?

Comment: HTML elementals?  Specifically, do you mean Fire, Water, Earth or Air?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically the problem is how to get underlying HTML from a DOM element. You can use `outerHTML` property for this:

```
data.img = $(source_data).find('img').eq(1).clone()[0].outerHTML;
```

which should return `<img src="path/pic2.png" title="picture 2" />` as a string.

**UPDATE**
JQuery templating engine automatically escapes values before displaying, to display raw html without escaping you need to modify your templates:

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="linkTemplate">
    <table><tr>
        <td>{{html link}}</td>
        <td>{{html img}}</td>
    </tr></table>
</script>
```

(`outerHTML` is still needed)

Comment: Not really. I used strings first and the outcome was non-rendered HTML strings, which is why I switched to DOM elements. Try the JS fiddle link.

Comment: I figured that out too and have my code working as intended, but still giving you credit. `{{wrap}}` can take objects, but html string and simpler `{{html}}` is better.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an example of some working code:

```
<td class="test"></td>
<script>
  $('.test').append('<img src="path/pic.png">');
</script>
```

Comment: It was just an example. I wasn't really worried about 'valid'.